# XNA - How do I change the texture of a 2D object?

Tags: xna, textures

I am on to make a table game, I successfully figured out how to make the arrow and to move the cursor on it (by tiles). Now I wanna find out how to make that if I hit the Enter key the tile's texture change to another.
I tried like this:

```
if (input.KeyPressed(Keys.Enter))
{
    cell[X,Y].Cell_texture = tile_texture;
}
```

but it doesn't really work.

Comment: it would be more interesting if you show your draw method...

Comment: If you are writing the texture per se in your Draw method, just draw the new one. If you don't care about the old texture (only used in this particular tile) use [Texture2D.SetData(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx). Otherwise, we need more info.

Comment: Maybe you should change states, not textures per see. And then draw the texture relative to that state.

Comment: If you have the asset name of the tile you want, you could just change `Cell_texture` using `Content.Load<Texture2D>('assetName')`

Comment: the cell class's draw method:
 public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
      {

            spriteBatch.Draw(Cella_texture, Cella_position, Color.White);
       
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cell` class change `Cell_texture` to a `byte`

Add 2 variables

```
public static Texture2D Texture1;
Tpublic staticexture2D Texture2;
```

And your switching logic

```
 if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
 {
      cell[X,Y].Cell_texture = 1;
 }
```

And in your draw method

```
if (cell[X,Y].Cell_texture == 0)
    //DRAW TEXTURE1
else (cell[X,Y].Cell_texture == 1)
    //DRAW TEXTURE2
```

This will allow you to have multiple cell types, and have a global Texture2D for better memory usage.

Comment: Also, Seeing your draw method could allow me to give better advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Varibles:
          Texture2D tile1;

Texture2D tile2;

```
 if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
 {
    tile1 = tile2;
 }
```